# Transform line chart with selection input into bar chart with d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts, bar-chart, linechart

This should be a really easy one, but I am stuck.

I want to transform a line chart with a selection input (to choose different data to plot) into a bar chart.

I was always able to do that with static data, but in this case I am stuck.

The snippet that works as a line is this:

```
svg.append("path")
   .datum(dataFiltered[0].values)
   .attr("class", "line")
   .attr("width", 0)
   .attr("d", valueline);
```

I tried to apply something like this:

```
svg.append("rect")
   .attr("class", "bar")
   .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.mes); })
   .attr("width", x.range())
    .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.jornalistas); })
   .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.jornalistas); });
```

It does not work. *(I took out this snippet from the code in JSBin)*

Could someone be kind enough to help me with this?

[Here is the code in JSBin](https://jsbin.com/cazovo/edit?html,js,output)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the function you're using at the end of the last line from

`d3.select('.line').datum(dataFiltered[0].values).attr('d', line)`

to

`d3.select('.line').datum(dataFiltered[0].values).attr('d', valueline)`

as you have not defined the function `line` anywhere!

Comment: That is true indeed, but only for selecting values and automatically changing the scale, but it is still not a bar chart

Comment: I think you need a different d3 scale for the barchart, and also need to call `data().enter()` on your appended rects